# Get form Drop down value with reference to below script using Jquery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to find out the existing value of info path form Drop Down on page load using jquery with reference to below script, Please try to get Drop Down using Class name or title except ID.

```
<span style="white-space: nowrap;" onmouseover="return LeafControl.OnWrappingSpanMouseOver(this, event);"
onmouseout="return LeafControl.OnWrappingSpanMouseOut(this, event);" class="a_jMoijPYJScd3O179_1 r_jMoijPYJScd3O179_1 bz_jMoijPYJScd3O179_1 b1_jMoijPYJScd3O179_1">
<select onchange="return (DropDownList.OnChange(this, event));" onfocus="return (DropDownList.OnFocus(this, event));"
    onblur="return (DropDownList.OnBlur(this, event));" id="ctl00_m_g_9b533b93_8578_445e_8f07_9d3d3923440c_FormControl0_V1_I1_D26"
    scriptclass="DropDownList" class="q_jMoijPYJScd3O179_1 m_jMoijPYJScd3O179_1 b0_jMoijPYJScd3O179_1 bq_jMoijPYJScd3O179_1"
    wrapped="true" direction="ltr" viewdatanode="39" formid="ctl00_m_g_9b533b93_8578_445e_8f07_9d3d3923440c_FormControl0"
    originalid="V1_I1_D26" tabindex="0" title="" style="direction: ltr">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="Pending" selected="">Pending</option>
    <option value="Approve">Approve</option>
    <option value="Reject">Reject</option>
    <option value="Change Topic">Change Topic</option>
</select></span>
```

Please help me to find out the value.

Thanks,
 Digambar

Comment: Please add more info, if you want to get value of selectbox, just use this: `$('select.className').val();`

Comment: `$('.q_jMoijPYJScd3O179_1 m_jMoijPYJScd3O179_1').val()` or `document.getElementsByClassName('.q_jMoijPYJScd3O179_1 m_jMoijPYJScd3O179_1')[0].value` (both assuming this is the only one, or the first one, element with this class name).

Comment: Pawel it give undefined for val() and null for text()

Comment: I gone through all above changes still waiting for result.. Also one more thing m uisng jquery-1.6.4.min.js JS.

Answer (score 1):

what i understood you might required one of following

using class name

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 

    //get the currently selected value   
    var value = $('.dropDownClass option:selected').val()

    // get the currently selected text:

    var txt= $('.dropDownClass option:selected').text();            
    });
```

using id

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

//get the currently selected value   
var value = $('#dropDownId option:selected').val()

// get the currently selected text:

var txt= $('#dropDownId option:selected').text();            
});
```

**More Info:**

- http://api.jquery.com/val/
- http://api.jquery.com/text/

Comment: OP stated that, for whatever reason, he doesn't want to rely on ID ;)

Comment: Tried both the way but its not working.Its infopath form code behind ..var txt= $('#dropDownId :selected').text();  after using this it gives null value in alert.

Comment: @user2630215 And you should replace dropDownId or dropDownClass with your original name in your code. I just gave dummy names. for instance '.dropDownClass' should be '.q_jMoijPYJScd3O179_1 m_jMoijPYJScd3O179_1' according your code

Comment: I gone through all above changes but still waiting for result.. Also one more thing m uisng jquery-1.6.4.min.js JS.

Comment: @user2630215 I dont know why you strange class name. I tested your code and came know that if you change class name to any simple name like test and my code works. Check it here http://jsfiddle.net/alam99/zp57Z/3/

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  var val = $('select.DropDownList option:selected').text();            
});
```

Comment: @user2630215 check the exact class name or ID. I have used sample class name.

Comment: I gone through all above changes but still waiting for result.. Also one more thing m uisng jquery-1.6.4.min.js JS.

Answer (score 0):

If your select element has this class name fixed (I mean if you are giving a static class name like this) then you could just do the following -

```
$(".q_jMoijPYJScd3O179_1 m_jMoijPYJScd3O179_1 b0_jMoijPYJScd3O179_1bq_jMoijPYJScd3O179_1").change(function(){
// variable text will contain the selected option as string
var text = $(this).children("option:selected").val(); 
});
```

Otherwise if your class is dynamic which I suppose is the case with your code, you can add another class name and then call the jquery with that class name. here's an example :

```
$(".myClass").change(function(){
// variable text will contain the selected option as string
var text = $(this).children("option:selected").val(); 
});
```

and add the class name "myClass" to the select element class attribute with a space in between the two class names

Comment: I gone through all above changes but still waiting for result.. Also one more thing m uisng jquery-1.6.4.min.js JS.

Comment: the class name that you are mentioning in your post - is it static or dynamic?

Comment: Class name, ID are static value.

Comment: No problem then! Just go with the first code block that I have mentioned. Isn't that working ? 

I know what could be happening if this isn't working - try adding http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js in place of jquery-1.6.4.min.js

Answer (score 0):

I believe MS has put a hook in IE so that infopath forms cannot be processed as normal web pages.  I have not been able to get any data from the page if the form is infopath generated.